# R loop to create dataframes based on column name prefix

Tags: r, loops

I have a very long data frame that has family members information in one row. I would like each family member to be it's own row. Each column starts with p1, p2... indicating the person in each household.

What i have managed to do is to create multiple data frames (15) separately then bind them.

```
df1<- master_df %>% select('family_id', starts_with('p1_')) 
colnames(p1)<-gsub("p1_","",colnames(p1)) %>%
mutate(person_id='01') %>% select(family_id,person_id,everything())  
df1$person_id <- paste0(df1$family_id, df1$person_id)
```

My data looks like Table 1 and i would like it to look like table 2

[image: My data looks like Table 1 and i would like it to look like table 2]

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: Have you looked at `pivot_longer`?

Comment: Your data: `tibble(id=100:102, person1_age=c(1,1,2), person2_age=c(2,2,1), person3_age=c(1,4,2), person1_sex=c(2,3,2), person2_sex=c(4,2,0), person3_sex=c(0,1,3))`. The solution: `... |> tidyr::pivot_longer(-id, names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", names_to = c("person", ".value"))`.

Comment: Knox, if my comment and the dupe-links don't help resolve your issue, please [edit] your question to provide usable data, show why the above code doesn't work for you, then @-ping me and we'll work through the issues (reopening if needed). Good luck!

Comment: BTW, your `%>%`-pipe is a _mess_. `gsub(..) %>% mutate(.)` cannot work, because `gsub` returns a character vector yet `mutate` requires its first argument to be a `data.frame`.